# WiX Ice64 error for shortcut parent directory

Tags: wix

I am trying to create a start menu shortcut for an application using WiX, the problem is that I am receiving an Ice64 error stating that the parent directory of the shortcut directory is not in the RemoveFile table.

I do not want to remove this parent folder (organisation folder) on uninstall as other applications may have shortcuts in other children of it.

My code looks like

```
<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="MyApplication" Level="1">
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="Components" />
  <ComponentRef Id="ProfilesShortcut"/>
</Feature>

 <Fragment>
  <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
   <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="OrgDir" Name="OrganisationName">
      <Directory Id="AppDir" Name="MyApplication" />
    </Directory>
   </Directory>
   <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
    <Directory Id="ProgFilesOrgDir" Name="OrganisationName">
      <Directory Id="ProgFilesAppDir" Name="MyApplication" />
    </Directory>
   </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
 <DirectoryRef Id="ProgFilesAppDir">
  <Component Id="ProfilesShortcut" Guid="*">
    <Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut"
                 Name="MyApplication"
               Description="My Application"
                Target="[#MyApplication.exe]"
                      WorkingDirectory="AppDir"/>
    <RemoveFolder Id="ProgFilesAppDir" On="uninstall"/>
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Organisation\MyApplication" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
  </Component>
 </DirectoryRef>
</Fragment>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feel free to add the remove file element to your shortcut component.

> Remove an empty folder if the parent component is selected for installation or removal.

The RemoveFolder element will only remove empty folders so if your product is not the only part of that suite installed it will leave the parent folder alone since other products will have put files/folders there. Consider the scenario where your product is either the only one installed (should remove the folder) or is the last one to be uninstalled from the suite (should remove the folder). In these two cases the folder should get removed. The order of RemoveFolder elements get defined might matter so I would test putting the ProgramFilesOrgFolder remove element before and after ProgFilesAppDir remove element just to see if one of them fails.

Alternatively you can just suppress ICE64 but then you will leave a folder behind once all the products are uninstalled. Not a huge deal really but might be annoying to some users.